# On windows is it possible to get dll's to look for dependencies in another folder without using the PATH environment variable?

Tags: c++, windows, dll, path, shared-libraries

On linux I am able to set the`RPATH` of a shared library to `$ORIGIN:$ORIGIN../lib`. This tells the DLL to look in the same directory as the shared library as well as in the `../lib` folder. I've read that on windows you just add the absolute path to `../lib` (for example) to the `PATH`. Is there an alternative to this method? I want my dll to look in the `../lib` folder but don't really want it on the path. Is this possible?

Comment: you can use [`SetDllDirectoryW`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-setdlldirectoryw)

Comment: Could also define your own environment variable instead of using PATH.

Comment: @RbMm, `SetDllDirectoryW` has the peculiar feature that it gets inherited by child processes in the PEB `ProcessParameters` `DllPath`, but only if it sets an actual directory. In other words, calling `SetDllDirectoryW(L"C:\\Windows")` overrides searching the working directory in the current process and child processes, but  `SetDllDirectoryW(L"")` removes the working directory from the DLL search path only in the current process.

Comment: Also, regarding `PATH` and the working directory, they're only searched unconditionally during process initialization. Once running, modern applications may elect to call `SetDefaultDllDirectories` or use loader flags such as `LOAD_LIBRARY_SEARCH_DEFAULT_DIRS`, which will not include the working directory and `PATH` directories in the DLL search path. In this case, legacy libraries that instruct users to add directories to `PATH` will fail to load. Applications need to be updated to add the required directories via `AddDllDirectory`.

Comment: @ErykSun also interesting that `SetDllDirectoryW` not accept `;` symbol in the path, despite this is valid symbol in file name. why at all `;` used as separator in path strings, but not say `*` or `|` which is not valid file symbols

Comment: @RbMm, I would have used "|" as the delimeter, but using ";" goes back to MS-DOS. It reserved all of the following symbols in filenames: `\/?*<>"`, `|:.`, and `;+,=[]`. Windows still reserves the first group -- the first two as path separators and the rest as wildcard characters. In the second group, most (but not all) filesystems reserve "|" and ":" (the file stream delimiter in NTFS), and "." is usually allowed. The API doesn't allow normalized filenames to end with ".", but it's possible with a verbatim path. The third group is allowed, but ";" should be avoided in directory names.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the main DLL dynamic/delay-loads the dependent DLLs, it can call [`SetDllDirectory()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-setdlldirectoryw) (or better, [`AddDllDirectory()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/libloaderapi/nf-libloaderapi-adddlldirectory)) before loading them.

If the main DLL static-links to the dependent DLLs, but the EXE dynamic/delay-loads the main DLL, then the EXE can call `(Add|Set)DllDirectory()` before loading the main DLL.

Otherwise, you will have to either:

- update the `%PATH%` environment variable.
- use an application manifest that specifies the paths of the dependent DLLs.
- use [DLL Redirection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dlls/dynamic-link-library-redirection).

Comment: The nearest to a Unix RPATH or RUNPATH that lists arbitrary directories is using a SxS assembly that lists the dependent files in the assembly manifest, with the assembly declared in the DLL's #2 embedded manifest. Normally the fusion loader will look for the assembly in WinSxS, the DLL's directory, and a subdirectory named for the assembly, but you can extend this in a config file beside the DLL (e.g. "spam.dll.2.config") that specifies a ["Probing"](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/sbscs/application-configuration-files#probing) path that lists relative paths to search.